# Generating bird eye view of image in OpenCV(Python) without knowing exact positions of reference points and camera properties

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, fisheye, topdown

I want to do some particle image velocimetry on dancing people but I was not able to record movies from the top (a bird's eye view). Instead, I managed to shot them from an upper position and my goal is to transform this series of images into a top/down bird's eye view using `warpPerspective` from openCV in Python. The issues that I have are the following:

- I do not have reference points on the image;
- I do not know the distortion of the camera (the movie was shot with a Nikon D7000 and a 18-140 mm Nikon varifocal lens).

Here is the image I want to transform

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/262ey.png)

P1, P2, P3 and P4 are reference points that I chose to transform the perspective. I chose them because I know, from the geometry of the white pillars in the image, they form a rectangle (approximately). Their position in pixel are (1248, 2160), (2730, 1764), (3336, 2994) and (4728, 2196) respectively.

Based on an earlier similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72750456/7876254), I tried to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72757527/7876254) but the results were poor. Here is my code

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


im = cv.imread("images/_DSC3318.JPG")
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
(height, width) = im.shape[:2]
assert (width, height) == (6000, 4000), "or whatever else"

K = np.eye(3)
K[0,0] = K[1,1] = 1000 # 500-5000 is common
K[0:2, 2] = (width-1)/2, (height-1)/2

dc = np.float32([-0.32,  0.24,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]) # k1, k2, p1, p2, k3
im_undistorted = cv.undistort(im, K, dc)

modelpts = np.float32([
    [0.,  6.],
    [8.,  0.],
    [8., 6.],
    [0., 0.]])*20

pts1 = np.float32([(1248, 2160),
                  (2730, 1764),
                  (3336, 2994),
                  (4728, 2196)])

pts2 = cv.undistortImagePoints(pts1, K, dc)
impts_undist = pts2.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
H = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(impts_undist, modelpts)
topdown = cv.warpPerspective(im_undistorted, H, dsize=(90*15, 60*15))
```

`K` and `cd` are some parameters (that I don't really understand) used to obtained an undistorted image;`pts1` are the coordinate in pixel of P1,...,P4 mentioned above; `pts2` are supposed to be the coordinates of `pts1` in the undistorted image, `modelpts` are the coordinates of P1,...,P4 in the bird's eye image (my ultimate goal) which does not work.

To illustrate my point here are the resulting undistorted image `im_undistort`

[Undistorted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h77w7.png)

And here is the final top/down view

[Top/down view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NKql.jpg)

My guesses to why it does not work are:

- I do not have a precise location of `modelpts` corresponding to `pts1`;
- the order of the points in `modelpts` do not correspond to the order of points in `pts1`, therefore generating a completely wrong top/down view;
- parameters `K` and `dc` used in `cv.undistort` are not precise enough to correct for image distortion (though I doubt it affect much since the undistorted image is not too "wrong").

Comment: I think your second assumption is right, your points don't seem to be in the right order. Try to swap P3 and P4 in pts1

Comment: @Tiphel I swaped both points and it got worst. As a general comment, I tried to swap all points but never did I managed to get a correct view. I now don't know if it is because of the order of points (as you suggested) or because the distances in the model are wrong. I used 6 and 8 because the distance d(P1,P2) ~ 6 m and d(P1,P3) ~ 8 m, so considering P1 as the origine (0,0) in the top/view image, therefore P2->(0,6); P3->(8,0); P4->(8,6). That was the idea to determine `modelpts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Original Image you attached, I mocked up a quick very simple wrapPerspective. As you only provided a screenshot of it instead of the raw image, my points won't match yours but you'll get the idea.

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

imagepath = r'.\originalImage.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(imagepath)

# Ratio 8m width to 6m height (4:3)
width = 200
height = 150

#Input points are read from the corners drawn in the reduced size screenshot provided
inputpts = np.float32([[268, 175], [470, 220], [329, 298], [120, 215]])
outputpts = np.float32([[0,0], [width-1, 0], [width-1, height-1], [0, height-1]])

m = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(inputpts, outputpts)
outimg = cv2.warpPerspective(img, m, (width, height), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

cv2.imshow('Result', outimg)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: wrapPerspective Result]

As a comment, the angle of the camera is very strong to extract a top down view of the desired area, your image will be stretched a lot.